# c++ find the scalar product of two doubles?

Tags: c++, algebra

I am trying to follow an algebraic equation, and convert it to c++.

I am now stuck on:

```
s.dx + x
```

and:

```
(s.dy + y) /a
```

s, dx, dy, x, y, and a are all doubles.

Google tells me that the . in the mathematical notation means the scalar product (http://www.rapidtables.com/math/symbols/Algebra_Symbols.htm), but how can I get that from doubles? What is this algorithm in c++?

Many thanks.

Comment: The dot operator in C++ is **not** the scalar product

Comment: Sorry, but this is what I call zero research efforts. `*` = scalar product.

Comment: Hi, the equation is not in c++, I am trying to convert it.

Comment: You might want to pick up a programming book. If you try to convert math to C++ you _will_ get confused by lines like `x = x + 1`.

Answer (score 3):

Google is wrong, you are looking for the `*` operator:

```
s * dx + x
(x * dy + y) / a
```

Comment: the OP wasn't googling for C++ syntax, but for the mathematical notation. So, google wasn't wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should write `s*dx+x` and `(s*dy+y)/a`.

Perhaps you (or somebody) misunderstood the `.` thing, perhaps because a number constant in code (immediate number like `1` or `1.0`) will have a different type depending whenever you use a `.`. So `10000 * 10000` is an integer multiplication, while `10000.0 * 10000.0` is an floating-point (double) multiplication. But here the `.` isn't an operator, but is part of the floating-point syntax.

As an operator in C++, a `.` is used to get a member of a object (variable or method).

Comment: FYI: mathematicians use the dot as a generic product operator.